# Jest ioredis mock - Bind mock to module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ioredis

In typescript, i have the following instantion of IoRedis.

```
import IoRedis from "ioredis";

const redis = new IoRedis({
    ...
});
```

While mocking in the test classes the following way. Decided to go with `ioredis-mock`, to solve this problem.

```
var IoRedis = require('ioredis-mock');
var ioRedis = new IoRedis({
    data: {
        ...
    },
});
jest.mock('ioredis', ioRedis);
```

Which results in an error.

```
TypeError: this._mockFactories.get(...) is not a function
```

I have tried alternative calls to mock `ioredis`, but have a hard time binding the test version of the mock to the one being resolved in my code. Mainly i think the `new IoRedis` is the culprit but my `javascript` experience is not sufficient to know which way to mock an import/require followed by an `new` keyword.

Comment: Did you read https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [es-6-class-mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks), i found an approach that worked, mocking constructor on a class.

```
var IoRedis = require('ioredis-mock');
var ioRedis = new IoRedis({
    data: {
        cacheKey: cacheData
    },
});
jest.mock('ioredis', () => {
    return function () {
        return ioRedis
    };
});
```

This snippet can be used to mock `ioredis`, which i couldn't find online either in documentation or Stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire example of how you are implementing test with oioredis and jest?

Comment: sadly no, this was a snippet from a project i'm no longer a part of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using :

```
const RedisMock = require('ioredis-mock');
jest.mock('ioredis', () => jest.requireActual('ioredis-mock'));

const redis = new RedisMock({
            port: <same as in production>,
            host : <same as in production>,
            data: { 'Key:1': [JSON.stringify({"state":"INITIAL","recordingError":null})] ,
                    'Key:2': [JSON.stringify({"JSONVersionId":"1.0","agentTack":"11ebd1d4})] ,
       }
    });
```